# Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger and Quiet Period do not work together

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-generic-webhook-trigger

I am using Generic Webhook Trigger with Quiet Period set to 1,5h and they somehow do not work together.
Each time the Generic Webhook Trigger triggers the build withing the Quite Period - it just adds new build to pending queue, not adding changes to existing one.

Is it a bug or some misconfiguration?

Thanks!

[image]

Tried looking for answer here and asked AIs but with no luck.
Seems some important piece of puzzle is missing from documentation or understanding, but do not know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is in 'Allow several triggers per build' option. According to https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/ParameterActionUtil.java#L29, if this options is turned off, each build receives a new random UUID parameter, that overrides params passed to build from Generic WebHook Trigger in unique way, thus triggering new unique build.